# Align child to neighbors child?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have these `UIView's` with 2 `UILabel's` as children:

[image: Views]

As you can see for each section there is a `UIView` containing 2 `UILabel's`.

I want these to align so that the left labels right edge are in the same X position.

The way I have done this in storyboard is `ctrl + drag` from a left label to another left label and align by `right = 0`.

But when running the app I get this:

[image: When running]

Its just like the right align constraints where disabled but I dont get any errors in console.

If you need more info just ask.

Comment: What constraints did you set on the section `UIView`?

Comment: @GonjiDev On the top view I have centerX, top distance. and on the others I just have top distance. On the labels I have them top.bottom.left/right = 0 and a distance between them.

Comment: I think the problem is that the others sections do not have a constraints for x position but just the top distance. That's why you see the sections on the left. But anyway you may not need constraints to align the labels on the right, just use the right text alignment.